# Split an array at a specific value C++

Tags: c++, arrays

Say I have an array like this:

```
int arr [9] = {2,1,5,8,9,4,10,15,20}
```

How can you split the array at a certain value threshold?  So say `int 8` is our splitting value, the end result would be two separate arrays (or a 2d array if you want to give that a shot) that in this example would be `arr1 [4] = {1,2,4,5}` and `arr2 [5] = {8,9,10,15,20}`.  `arr1` stores all the values in `arr` that are below `8` and and `arr2` stores all the values in `arr` that are `8` and above.

I haven't been able to locate sufficient documentation or examples of this being done and I think array manipulation and splitting is worth having examples of.

Comment: Array sizes are compile-time constant. You cannot do this at runtime, as it's impossible to know the size of the resulting arrays at compile time. This can only be done using dynamic allocations (`new int[x]`), using dynamic containers (like `std::vector<int>`) or if your array is a constant expression. In any case, you can't "shrink" an array. You will be left with `arr` with a size of 9 `int`s.

Comment: Tricky with an array. They don't split. You will have to create two new arrays of the correct sizes and copy the original  over to the new. If you don't much care, you could leave the original array intact and pass around indexes or pointers to the beginning and ends and simply display it ias two separate arrays.

Comment: Probably by creating a new array, then locating the threshold value.  All items after the threshold are *copied* to the new array.

Comment: Start here: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point

Comment: Unless you have to actually *split* the array, you may be able to just [partition it](http://ideone.com/7XpK82) using [`std::partition`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition). With that you can build separate dynamic arrays if you want, or tailor the usage code to actually use iterators and join the rest of the modern C++ world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [std::partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition), or if you want to maintain the relative order and not sort the data, [std::stable_partition](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition).

```
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <vector>

    int main()
    {
        int pivot = 8;
        int arr [9] = {2,1,5,8,9,4,10,15,20};

        // get partition point  
        int *pt = std::stable_partition(arr, std::end(arr), [&](int n) {return n < pivot;});

        // create two vectors consisting of left and right hand side
        // of partition
        std::vector<int> a1(arr, pt);
        std::vector<int> a2(pt, std::end(arr));

        // output results
        for (auto& i : a1)
            std::cout << i << " ";
        std::cout << '\n';
        for (auto& i : a2)
            std::cout << i << " ";
    }
```

[Live Example](http://ideone.com/eFs2ai)

Answer (score 2):

If you can use C++11 then this is one way of using the standard library:

Using a [partition_point](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition_point): (edited the example from the link)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::array<int, 9> v = {2,1,5,8,9,4,10,15,20};

    auto is_lower_than_8 = [](int i){ return i < 8; };
    std::partition(v.begin(), v.end(), is_lower_than_8 );

    auto p = std::partition_point(v.begin(), v.end(), is_lower_than_8 );

    std::cout << "Before partition:\n    ";
    std::vector<int> p1(v.begin(), p);
    std::sort(p1.begin(), p1.end());
    std::copy(p1.begin(), p1.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));

    std::cout << "\nAfter partition:\n    ";
    std::vector<int> p2(p, v.end());
    std::sort(p2.begin(), p2.end());
    std::copy(p2.begin(), p2.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
}
```

Which prints:

```
Before partition:
    1 2 4 5 
After partition:
    8 9 10 15 20
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm working on a solution with loops.  This is a work in progress.  Let me know what you think.

```
void splitarr(int arr[], int length) {
    int accu = 0;
    int accu2 = 0;
    int splitter = rand() % 20;
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i != splitter) {
            accu++;
        }
    }
    int arr1[accu];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i != splitter) {
            arr1[i] = i;
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i == splitter) {
            accu2++;
        }
    }
    int arr2[accu2];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        if (i == splitter) {
            arr2[i] = i;
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This line `int arr1[accu];` and lines like this are not valid C++.  Arrays must be declared using a constant to denote the number of entries, not a variable.  Why not just use the solutions that were already given, i.e. use the partitioning functions?